# Fix Size EdiText whe wrap line - chat layout

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, chat

[image]
How can i fix that ?

I'm trying a long time but no sucess, everytime when i wrap the line in edit text, the chat become invisble...  i dont know why happen this.

I erase the old file and write again with new xml codes, but i cant find the problem.

I'm using SlidingUpPanelLayout, but i dont think this is the problem..
the height is wrap content   `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in `edittext` and in `recyclerview` is `matchparent`

Can someone help me out with this ?

Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
    sothree:umanoOverlay="false"
    sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/list">

<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<!--android:background="@drawable/fundo_chat"-->
<!--android:background="@color/white"-->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--#####################################  HERE IS RECYCLE VIEW LAYOUT ############################### -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_chat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="@+id/layout_envio_msg"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/telegramfundo_chat"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/indicador_msg_whats"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="5dp"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

    <!--#####################################  HERE IS RECYCLE VIEW LAYOUT ############################### -->



    <!--#####################################  HERE IS EDIT TEXT LAYOUT ############################### -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_mensagem_fundocontrolbg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/layout_envio_msg"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/botao_emoji"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/botao_hash"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="@color/Transparent"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/emotion_chat"
            android:tint="#1673fd"></ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/botao_hash"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edit_text_message"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/botao_emoji"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/botao_emoji"
            android:background="@color/Transparent"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search_hashtag_chat"
            android:tint="#d40040"></ImageButton>

        <hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_message"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/botao_hash"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/botao_hash"
            android:hint="Digite uma mensagem..."
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="17sp" />



        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/botao_mic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edit_text_message"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/edit_text_message"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit_text_message"
            android:background="@color/Transparent"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/chat_record"
            android:tint="#006909"></ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/botao_send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/botao_mic"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/botao_mic"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/botao_mic"
            android:background="@color/Transparent"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/send_chat"
            android:tint="#1f4374"></ImageButton>

    </LinearLayout>


    <!--#####################################  HERE IS EDIT TEXT LAYOUT ############################### -->



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment_layout"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_bg_action_down"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="invisible">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_bg_action_down"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <!--<fragment-->
        <!--android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="150dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="100dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginTop="100dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"-->
        <!--android:visibility="visible" />-->

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_Grab"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:background="@color/Transparent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/grab_video" />

    </RelativeLayout>




    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/typing_frame"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="520dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_bg_action_down_typing"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/typing_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Digitando..."
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>




<!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"

    android:focusable="false"
    android:id="@+id/dragView">

    <!--<LinearLayout-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="68dp"-->

        <!--android:orientation="horizontal">-->

        <!--<LinearLayout-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:backgroundTint="@color/amber_400"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="68dp">-->

        <!--<TextView-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/name"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="0dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
            <!--android:textSize="14sp"-->
            <!--android:gravity="center_vertical"-->
            <!--android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>-->

        <!--<Button-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/follow"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:textSize="14sp"-->
            <!--android:gravity="center_vertical|right"-->
            <!--android:paddingRight="10dp"-->
            <!--android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>-->
        <!--</LinearLayout>-->

    <!--</LinearLayout>-->

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:background="#2d5d82"
    android:id="@+id/Painel_Informacao"

    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="68dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Nome_Video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
            android:maxLength="25"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
            android:text="Aguardando..."
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TempoCorrido"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Aguardando..."
            android:textColor="@color/yellow_600"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Duracao"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Aguardando..."
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Botao_Compartlilhar_Video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Transparent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/sharev"
            android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"

          />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Botao_Compartlilhar_Video_Amigo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Transparent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/video_friend"
            android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"

            />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Botao_Desligar_Video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="330dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:background="@color/Transparent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/offv" />




    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"

    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

    android:background="@color/Transparent"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/black"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/youtube_miniplay"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:visibility="visible" />





    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>








    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/Conteudo_Dinamico"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </ScrollView>

    <!--<TextView-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:text="The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Section 1.10.32 of  written by Cicero in 45 t perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?1914 translation by H. RackhamBut I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete accouof the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."/>-->
    <!--</ScrollView>-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand of your question, is that you want your recyclerview (where the actual chat resides) to appear above the edit text. so how about changing your recyclerview to this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_chat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout_envio_msg"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/telegramfundo_chat"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />
```

What i did is the following; I removed your align parent bottom. Because this aligns it with the bottom of your `@+id/layout_envio_msg`, and i understood you wanted it to appear above. So i replaced that with `android:layout_above="@+id/layout_envio_msg"`

A little tip for future questions: try to only add relevant code. Too much irrelevant code can be confusing as we don't understand your specific use case for all of it.

~Greetings

Comment: work! but the edittext background is gone .. 
its not rounded anymore..

 android:background="@drawable/chat_mensagem_fundocontrolbg" 

when i put layout above

Comment: Can you update your question and point out what you mean? Please also post a new screenshot along with it

Comment: I fix it! 
Thanks Ellisan!

Comment: Good to see, please my answer as "the answer" if it was correct!

Comment: how can do that ?

Comment: There is a small checkmark at the side of the answer